# How do I query an Access Database in Excel where the fieldName may not always be the same

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I run the following query in Excel:

```
MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [RFS_QTR_DATE] = #31/12/2025#"
```

There are however tables where the `RFS_QTR_DATE`-field is differently spelled. (e.g. `RFLS_QTR_DATE`)

What is always the same is the  part `QTR_DATE`

my  question is, is there a way to  catch this, for example with a wildcard  or something?

Comment: Not overly farmiliar with SQL but did you simply try `MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [*QTR_DATE] = #31/12/2025#"`? Just asking as `*` is a wildcard you are already using in the query.

Comment: I'd say if you're field names are changing you need to have another look at the design of your database.  The only way I can think of is to use VBA to look at each field name, decide which one it should use and update your SQL string.

Comment: @SamuelEverson, This did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the field positions are constant and a VBA solution is not desired, you can assign field names to positions with a `UNION ALL` query, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Id As FirstFieldName, CStr(Id) As SecondFieldName, CDate(Id) As RFS_QTR_DATE
    FROM MSysObjects
    WHERE FALSE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
)
WHERE RFS_QTR_DATE = #31/12/2025#
```

Comment: Good answer.  Didn't consider that workaround - been about five years since I've played with Access so a bit rusty. :)

Comment: @Erik A, it gives an error for `MSysObjects`

Comment: Then take any other table, the table doesn't really matter, it just needs to be a table and field that exist and MSysObjects exists in all Access databases, but it sometimes comes with rights issues. You could just take `MyTable` as well, and if you're unsure about all field names, choose 0 instead of Id

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the field name in VBA by querying the DAO object model.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim fldName As String
Dim MyQuery As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tbl = db.TableDefs("MyTable")
For Each fld In tbl.Fields
    ' Name ends with _QTR_DATE
    If fld.Name Like "*_QTR_DATE" Then
        fldName = fld.Name
        Exit For
    End If
Next fld

If fldName = "" Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, Description:="Can't find QTR_DATE field in table."
End If

MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [" & fldName & "] = #31/12/2025#"
```